soon or quickly？
I was told that the second sentence is more suitable and think so just because, and I am asking to know the reason.
1. I know you're a flexible person who can build good relationships with people in new places soon
2. I know you're a flexible person who can quickly build good relationships with people in new places

Quickly and soon mean different things. Quickly means fast; soon means beginning at a time in the near future. "I am shopping quickly" = "I am running around the store." "I am shopping soon" = "I will be going out to the store in the next few minutes."

Both 'quickly' and 'soon' are subjective - for example, what one person thinks is "quick" may not seem so to another. Children are often less patient than adults ("are we there yet?"). Likewise, a length of time that is 'quick' in one context may not be another - 24 hours is a quick turnaround for an Amazon delivery but not for a food order.
But both adverbs are different in an important way. They are both relative measurements of time, but relative to different things. You can say something is "coming soon" when you are already waiting for it, so it is relevant only to the present moment. In contrast, you can say something will come quickly when te wait hasn't even begun; for example, "if you order it now, it will come quickly".
In your examples, you are speaking about a person's potential ability to do something quickly if they were to go to a new place. You're not referring to a specific starting point so you cannot use 'soon' - you should use 'quickly'.
When something is a certainty and there is a known starting point then you can use 'soon' it would normally be placed differently, for example "when you move, you'll soon make new friends".
